# Cross Compiling KConfig is not working

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile kconfig, which supposedly works on android, for android but am faced with the following

```
In file included from /home/dashed/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_algo.h:59:0,
from /home/dashed/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/algorithm:62,
from /home/dashed/android-qt/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:109,
from /home/dashed/android-qt/include/QtCore/QtGlobal:1,
from /home/dashed/Documents/kconfig/src/core/kconfigbase.h:29,
from /home/dashed/Documents/kconfig/src/core/kconfig.h:27,
from /home/dashed/Documents/kconfig/src/core/kconfig.cpp:23:
/home/dashed/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu- 
libstdc++/4.9/include/cstdlib:72:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdlib.h>
                ^
```

I generated the makefile with :

```
cmake     -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/ECM/toolchain/Android.cmake -DECM_ADDITIONAL_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/home/dashed/android-qt -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dashed/android-kf5 ..
```

what can I do to compile it successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

I sorta 'solved' this by updating my ndk. I was using r10e to compile qt but using r17b is successful.